# Why can't I save an object's methods as properties of another object literal

Tags: javascript, function, methods, object-literal

The code below is used to note some methods to run in particular circumstances so they can be called using a simpler syntax.

```
var callbacks = {alter: SPZ.sequenceEditor.saveAndLoadPuzzle,
                 copy: SPZ.sequenceEditor.saveAsCopyAndLoadPuzzle,
           justSave:SPZ.sequenceEditor.saveAndLoadPuzzle};
```

But the code keeps returning an empty object. I've checked with console.log that the methods are defined. I've also tried changing the names, invoking an empty object and then adding the properties as eg callbacks.alter, and tried other changes that shouldn't matter.

Why won't this work?

[Demo](http://wheresrhys.co.uk/resources/sperrordemo.html)

error is on line 238 of puzzle.js

Comment: That code should work.  Can you post a demo?

Comment: Yep, thought it might need one. Added a link above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is the problem? Will the properties be `undefined` or the calls just not work correctly?

If the latter, the problem is most likely that when calling the methods, `this` will no longer refer to `SPZ.sequenceEditor`, but your `callbacks` object; to solve this problem, use the helper function `bind()` (as defined by several frameworks) or wrap the calls yourself:

```
var callbacks = {
    alter: function() {
        return SPZ.sequenceEditor.saveAndLoadPuzzle.apply(
            SPZ.sequenceEditor, arguments);
    },
    copy: function() {
        return SPZ.sequenceEditor.saveAsCopyAndLoadPuzzle.apply(
            SPZ.sequenceEditor, arguments);
    },
    justSave: function() {
        return SPZ.sequenceEditor.saveAndLoadPuzzle.apply(
            SPZ.sequenceEditor, arguments);
    }
};
```

The `apply()` is only necessary if the methods take arguments. See details at [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Function:apply).

Comment: THe problem is taht after adding teh properties to the object if I console.log(callbacks) it's an empty object literal i.e. {}. I don't even get 'undefined'.

Comment: Although your answer has apparently worked. Not completely sure why yet, but will work on that. CHeers

Comment: In the end I found I could root through all the methods and replace 'this' with more solidly anchored references to the object. Strange, though, that firebug gave so little feedback as to what the problem was.