# Why can't I create a method equal to a global function within this object literal? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

Update: Thanks @Mathletics - I used an `=` when I should have used a `:` inside the object literal notation. `setAge: setAge` works perfectly inside the object literal.

In the Codecademy JavaScript track, the following problem occurs:

```
// here we define our method using "this", before we even introduce bob
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};
// now we make bob
var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;
bob.setAge = setAge;

// make susan here, and first give her an age of 25
//var susan = {age: 25, setAge = setAge}; //does not work
var susan = new Object();
susan.age = 25;
susan.setAge = setAge;

// here, update Susan's age to 35 using the method
susan.setAge(35);
```

I want to set `susan.setAge` to the global function, `setAge`. When I try to do it using object literal notation it does not work, but if I use `new` and then use dot notation it does work.

I tried `setAge = global.setAge` inside the object literal notation as well, but that failed. `setAge = this.setAge`, `function setAge = setAge`, `function setAge = this.setAge` and `function setAge = global.setAge` all also failed.

I tried researching related questions on Stack Overflow but [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816846/why-cant-i-save-an-objects-methods-as-properties-of-another-object-literal) [weren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265055/creating-properties-in-literal-object) very related. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433008/why-does-one-need-to-call-the-function-in-an-object-constructor-in-order-to-us?rq=1), while about a similar example, seems to be about the author's confusion between creating a method within an object and calling a global method using `.apply()`, which he or she does not appear to be aware of.

Comment: Did you actually use `=` instead of `:` inside your object?

Comment: Ah that's a shame...well spotted! If you make an answer I'd be glad to confirm it.

Comment: voting to close - it's just a trivial typographical error, not a real problem.

Comment: downvoting here is unhelpful. i tried my best here, doing research and trying different code examples etc. this is not the most helpful attitude to have towards newcomers of the site, who are probably just as likely as everyone else to make a typographical error. codecademy's compiler doesn't tell me where the error in the code is (and neither does jsfiddle, or at least i haven't figured out how to get it to do that), so this was rather petty.

Comment: @bobo you would have had an error in the console if you opened it and checked. And it's not a downvote, it's a vote to close.

Comment: @Mathletics - someone else downvoted me, and apparently took back their downvote after my comment, so it seems like it was effective (though it appears you have added a downvote of your own). No problem with the vote to close from me, though juvian's answer seems pretty helpful right now, and I still have some questions about it, so leaving it up for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sintax is wrong:

```
var susan = {age: 25, setAge : setAge}; // : instead of =
susan.setAge(35);
console.log(susan.age) // will show 35
```

You could also try a different approach:

```
function Person(params){
    params=params || {};
    this.age=params.hasOwnProperty("age") ? params.age : null;

    this.setAge=function(age){
        this.age=age;
    }
}

var susan = new Person({age:25});
susan.setAge(35);
console.log(susan.age) // outputs 35
```

As you have mentioned, using arguments saves a few lines, as its always an object:

```
function Person(){
    this.age=arguments.hasOwnProperty("age") ? arguments["age"] : null;
    this.setAge=function(age){
        this.age=age;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, @juvian, a couple questions:
how does javascript know where to look when you write `["age"]` as the first value in your conditional? also, why can you not use `arguments[]` instead of the `params` value you've made? and what does it mean to have an OR in your assignment: `params=params || {};` thanks

Comment: I haven't been able to find them. Could you provide links? Here are the search terms I used for each question:
1. I don't know what to search for for this question that is distinct from my queries for the second question.
2. `arguments vs params`, `arguments vs params javascript`
3. `or in assignment `, `var = ||`, `var = || javascript`, `or in assignment javascript`

It's interesting how many SO members offer a practiced unhelpfulness to newer members.

Comment: @bobo Sorry my mistake! Should have been `params["age"]` , already fixed it. Not used to use arguments, but yeah could use them. Regarding the `params=params || {};` , its just in case you do `var susan = new Person();` so if you do not sent any param(params is undefined), I set it to an empty object for it to work. Params is just the name I chose for the object, could be named data as well. Using arguments it would save a few lines, check edited answer

Comment: thanks @juvian! as an fyi, the comment above yours was addressed to another user, who appears to have withdrawn his comment. thank you for your help and kindness both!